# Nothing is displayed when loading my WebGL2 html file

Tags: javascript, html, webgl2

I am reading a book on WebGL2. I am new to both HTML and WebGL and am trying to educate myself.

I have a problem with loading one of the examples of the book, which is posted [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Real-Time-3D-Graphics-with-WebGL-2/blob/master/ch01/ch01_04_showroom.html).

For convenience, I have put the first few lines of the HTML code in below.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Real-Time 3D Graphics with WebGL2</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/common/images/favicon.png" />

  <!-- libraries -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/common/lib/normalize.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/lib/dat.gui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/lib/gl-matrix.js"></script>

  <!-- modules -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/utils.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/EventEmitter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/Camera.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/Clock.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/Controls.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/Floor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/Light.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/Program.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/Scene.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/Texture.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/Transforms.js"></script>

  <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  
...
```

When I open the HTML code in Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge nothing is displayed although I am using the exact same code. It is supposed to show the following.

[image]

I have checked that WebGL is enabled in my browsers but I still have the issue. Do I need the libraries and modules listed in the HTML in the same directory or do they all come with the browsers?

How can I debug my issue? Is the problem related to loading the libraries?

Comment: did you copy all the files? (models, commons etc.) how do you run it? on the server or from local file? it won't work from local file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with relative in HTML file in a subdirectory accessing libraries from other folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70552986/issue-with-relative-in-html-file-in-a-subdirectory-accessing-libraries-from-othe)

Comment: I answered your question here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70556123/10797718