# Issue with relative in HTML file in a subdirectory accessing libraries from other folders

Tags: html, path

I have an issue with the path definition of the libraries and models that are used in an HTML file using WebGL. The HTML file can be found [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Real-Time-3D-Graphics-with-WebGL-2/blob/master/ch01/ch01_04_showroom.html), which is an example code for a WebGL2 book.

The HTML file itself is sitting locally in the following directory in my computer.

```
C:\Users\bob\Desktop\Book\ch01\ch01_04_showroom.html
```

The libraries and other sources are located in

```
C:\Users\bob\Desktop\Book
├───ch01
|   └───ch01_04_showroom.html
├───ch02
└───common
    ├───images
    │   └───cubemap
    ├───js
    ├───lib
    └───models
        ├───audi-r8
        ├───bmw-i8
        ├───ford-mustang
        ├───geometries
        ├───lamborghini-gallardo
        └───nissan-gtr
```

The parts of the code that I have issues with are in the following

**ch01_04_showroom.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Real-Time 3D Graphics with WebGL2</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/common/images/favicon.png" />

  <!-- libraries -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/common/lib/normalize.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/lib/dat.gui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/lib/gl-matrix.js"></script>

  <!-- modules -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/utils.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/EventEmitter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/Camera.js"></script>
  
  ...
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';

    // ...

    function configure() {

      carModelData = {
        // This is the number of parts to load for this particular model
        partsCount: 178,
        // The path to the model (which I have issue with on my computer)
        path: '/common/models/nissan-gtr/part'
      };
    }

...
```

I have issue defining the path for `href`s and `src`s. Also the one in the javascript function:

```
path: '/common/models/nissan-gtr/part'
```

If I use the code as it is posted in [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Real-Time-3D-Graphics-with-WebGL-2/blob/master/ch01/ch01_04_showroom.html) nothing will be displayed in my Google Chrome, just an empty page.

So, I have changed paths from

```
/common
```

to relative paths:

```
./../common
```

but still, I am not able to load the HTML correctly. I see the gridded floor with an incomplete menu but the car is not displayed yet as in the following snapshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a security, Chrome doesn't let you load local files through `file:///...` for security reasons.

The purpose of this security is to prevent external resources from gaining access to your system, which could allow them to modify or steal files

[image]

### Solutions

- The best solution is to run a little http server locally since you can follow the steps from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33801287/10797718) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320098/10797718).
- Or, *maybe others will bring it up so I'll mention it*, you can also launching Google Chrome from the command line with the flag: `--allow-file-access-from-files`, **but this isn't recommended** since Chrome doesn't allow this behaviour to protect you.